# How to get an array of attributes from a jQuery collection in which they share an attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

If I have this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="tag" data-tag-id="1" checked="checked">
 <input type="checkbox" class="tag" data-tag-id="2">
 <input type="checkbox" class="tag" data-tag-id="3" checked="checked">
 <input type="checkbox" class="tag" data-tag-id="4" checked="checked">
```

I know how to fetch all checked checkboxes:

```
 $(".tag:checked");
```

The above returns three DOM objects:

```
 [{checkbox object}, {checkbox object}, {checkbox object}]
```

My question is: **How can I fetch a collection of data-tag-id?** I want, with one query, to get this:

```
 [1, 3, 4]
```

This doesn't do the job:

```
 $(".tag:checked").data("tag-id")
```

I searched a lot but most google results throwed: *"how to select multiple data attributes"*, which is another different thing, ie: `$("[data-bar=...][data-foo=...]")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and generate an array of *tag-id*.

```
var arr =  $(".tag:checked").map(function(){
    return $(this).data("tag-id")
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mDF75/)

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize an array and loop through your checked items..

```
var dataArray = [];
$( ".tag:checked" ).each(function(){
    dataArray.push( $(this).attr( "data-tag-id" ) );
});
```